# Installing Gem into ChefDK via Chef

Tags: chef-infra, chefdk

I want to install a Gem ([kitchen-docker](http://rubygems.org/gems/kitchen-docker)) into [ChefDK](http://www.getchef.com/downloads/chef-dk/mac/)'s Gem path.

What is the best way to install this Gem via Chef itself? Is there a more clever solution than the following?

```ruby
execute "chef gem install kitchen-docker" do
  user "jenkins"
  not_if "chef gem list | grep ^kitchen-docker"
end
```

Some background information: I want to use ChefDK in Jenkins on our CI server to do cookbook testing. The CI server itself should be provisioned by Chef, of course.

Comment: I also tried to set `gem_binary` for the `gem_package` provider, but I think this only installs the Gem into `/root/.chefdk/gems` (at least it was not available to the `jenkins` user then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, in order to install a chef gem system-wide (into `/opt/chefdk/`), the parameter `--no-user-install` of the `gem` command can be used through the `gem_package` resource:

```rb
gem_package "kitchen-docker" do
  gem_binary "/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/gem"
  options "--no-user-install"
end
```

This installs the gem and makes it available to all users running chefdk on the system.

Comment: This looked nice, but honestly didn't work for me.  It didn't fail, but upon testing it put it in the root users gems

Comment: Really? I am still using this and it works for me exactly this way. The gem is then installed in `/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/kitchen-docker-2.3.0`.

Comment: Well I guess it would depend on how the environment variables/ GEM_HOME and GEM_SYSTEM are set.  I THINK I properly use the eval $(chef-shell init bash) for all users. I'll poke around a bit more to see why I couldn't get yours to work

Comment: But how do you use `chef-shell init` inside a chef run? I mean.. there might be ways, but it doesn't feel so right.

Answer (score 3):

Run this:

```
chef gem install kitchen-docker
```

This install gen un chefdk path.

Best regards!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I was suggesting. But that's not idemponent and I was asking if there is even a more clever way.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet worked for me to create a resource allowing me to do
`chef_dk_gem "kitchen-dokken"`

It's a lot hackier than I'd like but because of issues with [CHEF-2288](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-2288) I otherwise had a lot of  troubles getting the gem into my target user, and having the env variables for GEM* setup correctly with chef-dk

```rb
action :install do
    include_recipe "chef-dk"
    execute "setup chefdk gem #{gem_name}" do
        command "runuser #{gem_user}  -c '/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/gem install #{gem_name}'"
        not_if "/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/gem list #{gem_name} | grep #{gem_name}'", :user => gem_user
    end
end
```